# jHipster H2 console not working

Tags: h2, jhipster

I am working on monolithic application in which there are some custom entities . When I access the H2 Console via Administration tab . It causes the app to restart when I click the connect button . I am not able to understand why this is happening  . Can anyone help me to figure it out .

In logs :

```
DEBUG 971  --- [  Thread-51] com.mydomain.mytable1 : close successful. 
DEBUG 971  --- [  Thread-51] com.mydomain.mytable2 : close successful. 
DEBUG 971  --- [  Thread-51] com.mydomain.mytable3 : close successful. 
.
.
```

This is causing an issue to access the database via console although , there is no issue while accessing API . Executing queries also result in `localhost refused to connect` . I am new to jHipster and H2.

Configuration :

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
        include: swagger
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: true
        livereload:
            enabled: false # we use gulp + BrowserSync for livereload
    jackson:
        serialization.indent_output: true
    datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/mydatabase;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
        username: frothers
        password:
    h2:
        console:
            enabled: false
    jpa:
        database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedH2Dialect
        database: H2
        show-sql: true
        properties:
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: io.github.jhipster.config.jcache.NoDefaultJCacheRegionFactory
```

Answer (score 2):

Why disabling the h2 console if you want to access it?

```
 h2:
    console:
        enabled: false
```

Just turn `enabled` to `true`.

Comment: Thank you for answering . But I already tried that also . That didn't work .  What I tried recently is spring:devtools:restart:enabled:false . This fixes my problem . Can you please briefly explain me what can be reason for it.

Comment: Maybe because when you connect h2, you changed the default values and so h2 modified `target/classes/.h2.server.properties` which triggered a restart. If this is the case, this path should be excluded https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-exclude

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will check this out with my set up .